# Windows 10 IoT Core dies after a few hours

Tags: windows-iot

I've been running Raspbian on a few Raspberries with months of uptime. Now, I've started to try out Windows 10 IoT Core on a **Pi 3** in order to run F# programs with an up-to-date .NET (Raspbian has a very outdated Mono, 2+ years old). I'm running headless, logging in with SSH.

After 2-4 hours of running Windows, the Pi stops responding. SSH connection drops, it stops replying to pings, it disappears from the IoT Dashboard "My Devices" list and the CPU gets too hot to touch. Reboot doesn't help, I have to reflash the SD card in order to boot the Pi again.

Does anyone recognise this problem?

(I'm controlling my Pi:s from a laptop and don't have a monitor. Never needed one for trouble shooting before, because Raspbian never gave me trouble like this.)

Comment: The temperature of the CPU you mention hints at an early demise for the Pi.

Comment: The Pi itself seems to be ok. Raspbian boots and runs flawlessly with a cooler CPU.

Comment: If you are just wanting to run an updated version of Mono, I'm running Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on my RPi3 and `mono --version` reports 4.4.2.11

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks, switching to Ubuntu Mate sounds like the easiest way for me to run F# on the Pi.

Comment: Bummer - Booting with Ubuntu Mate, I can't reach the Pi via SSH. Apparently Mate is not made for headless installations, so it needs a screen and keyboard to enable SSH. Any way this can be fixed by editing some file on the SD card?

Comment: I didn't see that you didn't have a monitor, although do you have a TV with an HDMI? Mate runs a setup wizard the first time you run it, so you have to see it, after that you can disable the X Window system by running `graphical disable` in a console window and rebooting. Usually I install [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com) after getting the Pi up and running so I can manage it through a web interface.

Comment: Turns out there's an easier solution: Mono-project.com has their own repo that can be added, and it contains a Debian ARM build that seems to work fine (so far...) with Raspbian. http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives

Comment: How many volts/amps is your micro usb adapter providing? My PI froze randomly when using an underpowered adapter, but the issue went away when I used a PI-certified one.

Comment: This was with the Pi branded adapter. However, shortly after posting this in 2016, I went back to Raspbian and have since that never touched Windows IoT with a 10 foot pole.

Answer (score 1):

Its very likely iot is updating at that time. Generally, iot updates will download and then an update/reboot will be issued a few hours later. You can force the update by going to the web management console and clicking Update.

Comment: I had already updated and rebooted through the management console before IoT died.